# Error deploying rails 3.2 to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, console

I'm doing the One Month Rails tutorial (https://onemonthrails.com/), everything went fine until I tried to put the app on Heroku. It says that "Something went wrong" went I go to the Heroku app URL.

Here is what I had in my console. I have no cllue what the problem is.  I'm using Rails 3.2.14 and Ruby 1.9.3

[image: Error output]

([Image in HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV17V.png))

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to add the following line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline